# Android/Eclipse - Recursively include libraries in a project's build path

Tags: android, recursion, include, libraries, buildpath

The situation is the following:

- I have an Android library project (A) which has in its build path
  some other libraries (test1.jar, test2.jar, ..)
- I have a test application (B) which includes the (A) project and uses it

What happens is that I have to manually include the libraries (test1.jar, test2.jar, ..) in the (B) test application in order to get it working.

What I actually would like is that the libraries which are included in the (A) project get also included (or referenced, or else) in some way so that there is no need to include them manually. Is this plausible?

Thanks